# Avoid/Disable state preservation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm working on a small App having following sort of interfaces (for assumption) 

 **Launching Screen -> Screen X -> Screen Y**

The problem is that when I close the app and open it again simultaneously it again shows me the last seen screen and then later on shows **Launching screen** and then the initial view controller.

I've checked some other Apps as well but they aren't behaving this way e.g. google maps.

I also have implemented following two methods in AppDelegate as follows

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldSaveApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
```

But nothing is working. Can someone please suggest what should I do

Thanks.

Comment: When you say you "close the app", what exactly do you mean? Are you force-quitting the app or simply putting it in the background and returning to the foreground?

Comment: closing it forcefully. Not putting into the background.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help but you could always do as I do and make use of `NotificationCenter`

```swift
// In something like viewDidLoad
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(returnedFromBackground), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)

...

@objc func returnedFromBackground() {
    // Anything you want to preserve/save/do and then segue (or whatever you use) to your launching screen
}
```